# How to send data from me for all other users?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using IBM Mobilefirst platform to build and improve my application. I want when I send data to the server, the server send to all other clients.

Does IBM Mobilefirst platform support this ?

Answer (score 0):

Server will do one to one only you have to add a notification service layer that will post/broadcast to notify users.

Notifications like 
**APPLE APNS:** Server will send APNs to all corresponding devices and they individually request your data from server. Also it can fetch in background also.

OR

For instant Service use **MQTT** service that is much faster. You have to configure `Rabbit MQ`.